# execution failed to task ':app:mergeDebugResource'

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> There were multiple failures while executing work items
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_email_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_phone_iphone_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_email_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_home_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_phone_iphone_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
>   Error while processing /Users/macbookmd101/AndroidStudioProjects/dataprofile/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_phone_iphone_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/endblue": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique requires Android Support Library 23.2 or higher and Android Plugin for Gradle 2.0 or higher, and uses vector drawables only. The VectorDrawableCompat class in the Support Library allows you to support VectorDrawable in Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher.

Before using Vector Asset Studio, you must add a statement to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

For more details -[See more](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)